# Selenium Webscraping Twitter - Getting hold of tweet timestamp?

Tags: python, selenium, twitter

When inspecting a twitter results page, within the following class:

```
    <small class="time">
         ....
    </small>
```

Is a timestamp for each tweet 'data-time':

```
<span class="_timestamp js-short-timestamp js-relative-timestamp" data-time="1510698047" data-time-ms="1510698047000" data-long-form="true" aria-hidden="true">12m</span>
```

Within selenium i am using the following code:

```
tweet_date = browser.find_elements_by_class_name('_timestamp')
```

But looking at a single entry only returns, in this case, 12m.

How is it possible to access one of the other properties within the class within selenium?

Answer (score 1):

I usually use find_elements_by_xpath, this will let you grab a specific element from a page without worrying about names. Or so that's how it seems to work.

**EDIT**

Alright so I think I've got it figured out. First, find element by xpath and assign.

```
ts=browser.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="stream-item-tweet-929138668551380992"]/div/div[2]/div[1]/small/a/span')
```

Forgot that if you use "elements" instead of "element" you'll need to add something like this.

```
ts=ts[0]
```

Then you can use the get_attribute method to get the info associated with 'data-time' in the html.

```
raw_time=ts.get_attribute('data-time')
```

Returns

```
raw_time == '1510358895'
```

Comment: Hi Stew - using tweet_date = browser.find_elements_by_xpath('data-time') seems to be returning an empty list?

Comment: Right, the xpath is going to be something like //*[@id="question-header"]/h1/a.  That is the xpath of the title of this question. Easiest way I know of to get those is using chrome. Right click on the item, inspect, and then right click the bit of html code that is highlighted. There should be an option for Copy -> Copy XPath

Comment: I realised after posting! "//*[@id='data-time']/div/div[2]/div[1]/small/a/span" Is still not playing nicely...hmm.

Comment: Sometimes you'll need to play with it a bit to get the exact right bit of html selected. Like if the value is in a span tag, you might not want to select the whole thing. Unfortunately without being able to get to the page you're talking about, I can't give very exact advice.

Comment: For example, a search results page like this: https://twitter.com/search?q=giraffe&src=typd. I was actually hoping that: browser.find_elements_by_css_selector("span._timestamp[data-time]") would work, but also just returns the text time rather than timestamp

Comment: You're trying to get something like "Nov 10" right?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/159011/discussion-between-curious-student-and-superstew).

Answer (score 0):

Thank you to SuperStew who found the key to the answer - get_attribute()

My final solution for anyone wondering:

```
tweet_date = browser.find_elements_by_class_name("_timestamp")
```

And then for any date in that list:

```
tweet_date[1].get_attribute('data-time')
```

Comment: @iamsankalp89 I have to wait another day before being able to accept my own